# ord() expected a character, but string of length 6 found

Tags: python, python-3.x, ord

The variable is always being encrypted correctly, and it is a string, but when I try to add a string besides the variable it crashes and expects characters. Any suggestions?

```
monday_var = StringVar()
monday_box = tk.Checkbutton(self, state='active',  variable=monday_var, 
onvalue='Monday', offvalue='')
monday_box.grid(row=10, column=1)


def caesar():
    string_new = monday_var.get()
    new_file = open("personal decoded.txt", "w")

    key = -1
    decrypted_message = ""
    for i in string_new:
        letter_value = ord(i) + key
        if letter_value > ord("z"):
            letter_value -= ord("z") - ord("a") + 1
        decrypted_message = decrypted_message + chr(letter_value)

    new_file.write(decrypted_message)
    new_file.close()
```

Comment: Where is the code that raises the error? Do you mean something like `ord("foo")`, and if so, what would be the expected result of that? A list or tuple of values for the individual characters, or something else?

Comment: letter_value = ord(i) + key
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 6 found
That is the code that causes the error. It is supposed to create a file with the word monday in it which is encrypted

Comment: Sorry, but _that_ can not be the code that raises the error, at best _part_ of the code. Please try to provide a self-contained example that produces that error. Even if you were to pass a list to the `StringVar`, it would convert that list to a string, and then `i` should always be a single character of that string. There must be something weird going on in the remainder of your code. Adding the checkbox to a panel and a button that triggers the `caesar` function, the code does not produce that error.

Comment: @Cripyy please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

This Error you will get if pass a string to 'ord' instead of a character. 
Probably you are passing a string of length 6 to 'ord' function that's why this error you are getting.

```
In[55]: ord('a')
Out[54]: 97

In[56]: ord("rhia")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\LegacyApp\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", 
    line 2827, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
    File "<ipython-input-55-7cc3b9b0818e>", line 1, in <module> ord("rhia")
    TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 4 found
```

Here when I am passing 'a' to ord, it returns value but when I am passing a string ("rhia") it throws a TypeError because ord accept only a character or a latter.